# upgrade from windows server 2008 r2 std to enterprise

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

We recently had to upgrade our servers from Win 2008 R2 Standard to Enterprise. The upgrade method was DISM. After the upgrade, a lot of weird things started to happen.

Though Windows says it's been properly activated, we lost
1) RDP settings (disappeared from the Remote Setting tab of Properties of My Computer)
2) The option to join a domain is grayed out
3) The server had to 2 physical processors 12 cores each. Now, task manager or windows sees only 1 processor (or only 12 cores)
4) the amount of physical ram on this sever is 32 GB (Windows reports only 4 GB are usable)

Has anyone encountered this before ?
Thanks
Ravi

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2652825 does this apply

Comment: Yeah I have heard of this before, on this very site. I just can't find the link to it!

Comment: @tonyroth I will follow the steps for MS kb you provided and let know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This KB will take you through resolving your issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2652825

The issue is that your current install is tied to KMS and not MAK. Use the relevant KMS key from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793421.aspx and then use slmgr.vbs to set your key once the Transmog is done.

"Remember to activiate your server, or stuff like Remote Desktop will be disabled."

The above quote is incorrect all features work just fine you just get a black desktop.

Comment: FrontPage? Is that the correct KB in your link? Perfect example of why a single-link-only answer isn't really desirable here.

Comment: @jscott (and other downvoters) It's obviously a typo in the link, he has the correct link in the comment he posted above.  Still, a description of what the link is to would be a good idea.

Comment: fwiw, I've not down voted the answer. I had hope a comment would prompt the poster to add information to their answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you never re-activated Windows after the upgrade. Make sure you change the installed product key to one for Enterprise and you run through activation again.

Comment: We did activate Windows after the upgrade, by changing the key and going through the procedure. Windows even says it's activated. I wonder if we have to do this via command line also (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/f32d3a48-271e-49d7-ad82-852e21aa7f4d) last comment